# can we use static string in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

can we use static string in web application?

Is there any data switching between users who are all logged in same session?

Comment: What do you want to hold in that string? Where are you deploying the application?

Comment: What do you mean, every user has his own session ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static string will remain the same for every user like global variable or Cache object.

It has nothing to do with session or user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... see, i need to avoid using session state any ideas abt this..

Comment: Why? that's the way that you can memorize some data per user, it it's unreliable consider using `Sql Session Provider`, or if you want memorize some data for all users choose the `Cache` object.

Comment: See this answer for more about static variables in asp.net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874292/static-properties-across-different-asp-net-requests

Answer (score 1):

You can hold stuff across sessions in an `Application` object if that's what you want. See e.g. [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2010/03/01/difference-between-asp-net-sessions-application-variables-and-cache-objects.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The string would be the same for all users but in this case you may better off using a `const`.