# Static properties across different ASP.NET requests

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I create a static property `MyLanguage` and one request sets its value to `1`, while at the same time another thread sets it to `2` - what will be the final value of `MyLanguage`?

Does the single `MyLanguge` property gets shared across ASP.NET sessions?

Comment: No just a simple asp.net web page

Comment: Can you please put some effort into making your question clearer? It's a grammatical nightmare. :( I haven't had my morning tea yet, so perhaps it's just me, but this question could really use some work.

Comment: NO, If u Store your value 1 or 2 into session ..then it will be unique for each user.. session can't be shared its unique

Comment: Please have your morning tea first :)

Comment: For every client, session data is stored separately.

Comment: @AnantDabhi I am not setting session value i am setting static property value

Comment: Please Add ur code sample co we can understand batter

Comment: @wudzik Incorrect. Static doesn't have anything to do with statelessness; the value is stored as long as the AppDomain exists

Comment: If it is defined in the AppDomain.

Comment: is there any other options that distinct between two request other than session

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A static property/field is shared across the app domain. So all your sessions should see the **same value**.

The only exception is when you use the [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute on a static **field**, in which case each thread will see its own value. e.g.

```
[ThreadStatic]
static int counter = 0; // each thread sees a different static counter.
```

Comment: Erosnmez so it means that each session will have its own static value

Comment: no, unless you've specified [ThreadStatic], they should see a _shared_ value, not their own value.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about that only,

Answer (score 2):

It would be 2. Static fields, properties are shared between objects.So Latest set values will be updates for all the instances.

From MSDN

Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the **type itself rather than to a specific object**. The static modifier can be used with classes, fields, methods, properties, operators, events, and constructors, but it cannot be used with indexers, destructors, or types other than classes. For more information

Comment: I don't like the terminology of "shared between objects" - that suggests that they're *related* to the objects themselves, which they're not. They're related to the type. The field exists whether there are *any* instances or not.

Comment: It is just terminology. In real, it is shared by all the objects.

Comment: @Rajesh Subramanian you may want to alter your answer where you say statics are shared across objects - it's misleading, it's the same as saying `Environment.MachineName` is shared across object - while, in fact, they're completely unrelated. Statics belong to the type, not to individual objects.

Answer (score 0):

Statics are unique to the application domain, all users of that application domain will share the same value for each static property.

When you see the word static, think "there will only be one instance of this." How long that instance lasts is a separate question, but the short answer is that it is variable.

If you want to store values specific to the user look into [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).